# Brightspot CMS can't render /render/article.jsp

Tags: java, content-management-system

Can't render /render/article.jsp!

Property 'headline' not found on type com.project.Article (javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException)

```
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:268)
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:221)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:355)
```

Toggle Stack Traces
An exception occurred processing JSP page /render/article.jsp at line 5

```
2: <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
3: <%@ taglib prefix="cms" uri="http://psddev.com/cms" %>
4:      <h1>RAJA RENDERING</h1>
5:     <h1><c:out value="${content.headline}"></c:out></h1>
6: 
7:     <cms:render value="${content.bodyText}"/>
```